# Symfony4: Expected argument of type "Categorie", "instance of App\Entity\Categorie" given at property path "categorie"

Tags: php, forms, symfony4

I am having an issue with the `EntityType` class in `Symfony 4` where I cannot find a way to make the form row return a string instead of an entity (`Categorie`). This is what I basically have as part of the form builder: `ProduitType`

```
$builder
        ->add('nom')
        ->add('prix')
        ->add('imgproduit')
        ->add('categorie', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Categorie::class,
            'choice_label' => 'titre'
        ])
    ;
```

My aim is to have this field return the title(`titre`) for the `Categorie` selected, not the entire entity (so, the exact same value as the '`choice_label`'). I've already tried adding `__toString` to my Entity `Produit` but its the same problem

this is my Entity `Produit` in which I am using `titre` from `Categorie` as an attribut named `categorie`

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Produit
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="produit", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="nom", columns={"nom"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_p_ct", columns={"categorie"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Produit
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=20, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="prix", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=false)
     */
    private $prix;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="imgproduit", type="string", length=200, nullable=false)
     */
    private $imgproduit;

    /**
     * @var \Categorie
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Categorie::class, inversedBy="categories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categorie", referencedColumnName="titre")
     * })
     */
    private $categorie;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId(int $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $nom
     */
    public function setNom(string $nom): void
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getPrix(): ?float
    {
        return $this->prix;
    }

    /**
     * @param float $prix
     */
    public function setPrix(float $prix): void
    {
        $this->prix = $prix;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImgproduit(): ?string
    {
        return $this->imgproduit;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $imgproduit
     */
    public function setImgproduit(string $imgproduit): void
    {
        $this->imgproduit = $imgproduit;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Categorie
     */
    public function getCategorie(): ?\Categorie
    {
        return $this->categorie;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Categorie $categorie
     */
    public function setCategorie(\Categorie $categorie): self
    {
        $this->categorie = $categorie;
        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }


}
```

How would I be able to achieve my goal?

Comment: How does the question title relate to the body?

Answer (score 0):

Read the error carefully, expected "Category", got "App\Entity\Category"
It should expect "App\Entity\Category" the problem is with your setter:

```
/**
 * @param \Categorie $categorie
 */
public function setCategorie(\Categorie $categorie): self
{
    $this->categorie = $categorie;
    return $this;
}
```

You are declaring the parameter type to be `\Categorie` from the [global namespace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php). What you need is `Categorie` from the current namespace (`App\Entity`) or `\App\Entity\Categorie`.
The solution is to change **ALL** of the occurrences of `\Categorie` to `Categorie` or `\App\Entity\Categorie` within the file but, especially in your setter method to resolve this particular error:

```
/**
 * @param Categorie $categorie
 */
public function setCategorie(Categorie $categorie): self
{
    $this->categorie = $categorie;
    return $this;
}
```

### OR

```
/**
 * @param \App\Entity\Categorie $categorie
 */
public function setCategorie(\App\Entity\Categorie $categorie): self
{
    $this->categorie = $categorie;
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I already tried that one but it ends up whith another error (Notice: Undefined index: titre)

Comment: @KhalilFathalli unrelated error, fix them one at a time.

Comment: @Evert how can I fix this one??

Comment: My answer fixes the error in this question, short answer to resolve the new error is to use `referencedColumnName="id"` or whichever column has `@ORM\Id`

Comment: I think maybe you are wanting this entity property to only be a string, not an entity. If that is the case then it should not be mapped with `ManyToOne` and the form should use  `ChoiceType` and run a query to fetch the choices from the Categorie table.

Answer (score -1):

SF 6.3

there is also other simpler thing making this error

if you have declared **int field in Entity**, but from function passing string and trying to save (flush) entity.

> if error apears on processing $request in controller - that is the
> simple mistake

Comment: Please share more details. How does the error you talk about relate to the given problem? Isn't your problem a completely new problem?

Comment: what you not understand? in database declared field type is INT (as in entity) and you try to save STRING, error apear. db SQLITE, no strict types configured in DB. ps: thx for rating down my answer. f d.

Comment: and the problem is more complexed in ENTITYTYPE (form) field 'query_builder' not working as before SF 5.1 - NOW (till SF 6.4 you need to create for each entity type field in form DATA TRANSFORMER - ridiculus..

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What makes you think that SQLite is in any way related to the initial problem?

Comment: dont care. You marked my helpful answer as WRONG, took my exp points before give me chance to add smth more.